# Why are bash brace expansions not working for commands?

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

Why is this working:

```
mkdir /dir/test{1,2,3}
```

and this not?

```
{chown httpd,chmod 700} /dir/test1
-bash: {chown: command not found
```

My Bash Version is:
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release

Comment: Perhaps `tee` + `xargs` can help if you have a very long path which you don't want to repeat each time: `tee >(xargs chown httpd) >(xargs chmod 700) <<< /dir/test1`.

Comment: You can also reference arguments in next command https://stackoverflow.com/a/3371299

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your brace expansion is not valid.  A brace expansion must be one *word* in the shell.

A word is a string delimited by unquoted spaces (or tabs or newlines, by default), and the string `{chown httpd,chmod 700}` consists of the three separate words `{chmod`, `http,chmod` and `700}` and would not be recognised as a brace expansion.

Instead, the shell would interpret the line as a `{chown` command, executed with the arguments `http,chmod`, `700}` and `/dir/test1`.

The simplest way to test this is with `echo`:

```
$ echo {chown httpd,chmod 700} /dir/test1
{chown httpd,chmod 700} /dir/test1

$ echo {"chown httpd","chmod 700"} /dir/test1
chown httpd chmod 700 /dir/test1
```

Note that even if your brace expansion had worked, the command would have been nonsensical.

Just write two commands,

```
chown http /dir/test1
chmod 700  /dir/test1
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the effect with quoting, or would that still not work?

Comment: Oh no, because you'd still have two commands on one line.

Comment: @Time4Tea One command, in fact, with the wrong arguments.

Comment: When you say "should", how would one be able to force multiple words? Or is it a "must"?

Comment: @syss It's "must" (I will change it in the text).  A brace expansion expands to a set of words. If the brace expansion itself contains spaces, then these have to be quoted, as I have shown.

Comment: Another example similar to the "mkdir"-example, but with an empty expression and some whitespace is `mkdir test{,2," three",\ four}` (creates directories "test", "test2", "test three", "test four")

Comment: If the brace expansion were performed at command line level instead of word level, that command would've made perfect sense; it just isn't and that's all that can be said about it. Simulating such a behavior with an eval: `eval {'chown http','chmod 0666'}' /tmp/foo;'`.

Comment: @mosvy Yes, with `eval` and with _very careful quoting_, it would be possible to  do what the user wanted.

Comment: @Kusalananda and wrong command name, as it'd be searching for an executable called "chown httpd" in `PATH`.

Comment: @JoL I don't think so actually. You would have to quote it en extra time for that. `eval {'"chown http"', ...}`

Comment: @Kusalananda I just tried `{"chown httpd","chmod 700"} /dir/test1` and got `bash: chown httpd: command not found`.

Comment: @JoL You left the `eval` out.

Comment: @Kusalananda Ah. I was initially responding to your "One command [...] with the wrong arguments" comment, which responded to a discussion on simply using quotes. I hadn't seen the later discussion on `eval`.

Comment: @JoL :-) that explains it.  In that case, you are absolutely right.

Comment: Worth noting, that if the goal is to shorten the command OP has to type, they could reuse `bash`'s history expansion to use the last command line argument as in `!#:1`. https://askubuntu.com/a/1109025/295286

Comment: @Kusalananda I wasn't suggesting to use eval in this case, I was trying to illustrate what would happen in a hypothetical shell where the brace expansion is performed at command line level -- a command line would be turned into 2 or more command lines and that usage would make perfect sense. My point is that your claim that the command would've been nonsensical in any case is [**begging the question**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petitio_Principii) by already assuming a `bash`-like shell in which that simply doesn't work, whether sensical or nonsensical.

Answer (score 6):

because, as mentioned in the man page, bash will perform the brace expansion on each word **after** splitting a command line into words.

So, that command line will be first split into `{chown`, `httpd,chmod` and `700}`, and then, since `{chown` is not a valid brace expansion pattern, it will be left as is and bash will try to run a command with that name.

This is the quote from the manpage:

> Expansion is performed on the command line **after it has been split into
>          words**.   There are seven kinds of expansion performed: brace expansion,
>          tilde expansion, parameter and variable  expansion,  command  substitution, arithmetic expansion, word splitting, and pathname expansion.

Notice the order, which is different from other shells (in `zsh`, the brace expansion will be performed after the arithmetic expansion, and the extra word splitting won't be performed at all).

The following will print `1 2` in `zsh` or `ksh`, and `x y` in `bash`:

```
f=; f1=x; f2=y; echo $f{1,2}
```

Comment: when you say "Notice the order" on the expansions performed, brace expansion comes before word splitting. 
And in your first line you say that brace expansion comes after word splitting.
I am confused by that

Comment: that's an **extra** word splitting which is done just before path expansion (globbing). if the `a` variable contains the string `x y`, then a command line like `echo $a` will be 1st split into `echo` and `$a`, then `$a` will be expanded into `x y`, and then **split again** into `x` and `y`, giving `echo`, `x` and `y` as separate arguments. The latter step will be done using the value of `IFS` ( not necessarily containing spaces) and does not happen in `zsh`.

Comment: Why then the line `VAR={1..10}` doesn't perform the brace expansion?

Comment: The answer of my question above is: `The text after the ‘=’ in each variable assignment undergoes tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal before being assigned to the variable` from bash reference guide.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have explained why the brace expansion doesn't work. Ignoring that question for a moment, you probably want to avoid repeating the filename, and there are other ways to do that. Either assign the file name to a variable, or use the `$_` special variable (it contains the last shell word of the previous command):

```
f="some long and ugly filename"
chown httpd "$f"
chmod 700 "$f"
```

or

```
chown httpd "some long and ugly filename"
chmod 700 "$_"
```

Comment: history expansion would also be an option, I just can't remember the correct expansion